How to use imported .LIB multiple times in LTSpice
I have downloaded a PSpice .LIB file from the manufacturer.
I imported this file using .inc NSS1C201LT1G.LIB in the SPICE directive dialog box. I need to use 4 of these in the schematic but receive Netlist error: Duplicated Instance Name.
Do I need to create 4 separate PSpice models with different names or is there a better way?


You changed the wrong text field. You need to change the text that says NPN to the name of your model. You need to leave alone the other text field that says Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.

You only need to import a model in a schematic once no matter how many instances of that component you need. The model is like a set of rules for a component type, you import that set of rules and then assign it to the individual instances of that component in your schematic.
